# View Requests in applications Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a web api project deployed on azure... I need to see all requests arrive to the APIs. 
I am almost sure that before I could see the requests but now I do not see anything... The strange thing is that now applications insights look like switched off... Here what I see when I go on azure:

[image]

So, when I go in Analytics on Applications Isights on Azure and I try to do a query on the `requests` table no result is found.

App. Insights is enabled:

[image]

And the instrument key is the same on azure and on my vs project:

[image]

What could be happened? Thank you

Comment: Did you use the correct instrumentation key? Are you looking in the right account and the right subscription? Did you enable AppInsights for the specific web API? Can you see the AppInsights messages when you debug the web API from Visual Studio? In short: give us some more info, we might be able to help.

Comment: ok give me time to answer, directly on post

Comment: @RickvandenBosch I have answered... AppInsights is configured on my dev environment (on azure), and I do not debug on dev.